# scipy.integrate.odeint fails depending on time steps

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations, odeint

I use python for scientific applications, esp. for solving differential equations. I´ve already used the `odeint` function successfully on simple equation systems.

Right now my goal is to solve a rather complex system of over 300 equations. At this point the `odeint` functions give me reasonable results as long as the time steps in the `t-array` are equal or smaller than 1e-3. But I need bigger time steps since the system has to be integrated over several thousand seconds. Bigger time steps yield the "excess work done.." error.

Does anyone have experience with `odeint` and can tell me, why this is the case, although the `odeint` function seems to choose its time steps automatically and then displays the results that match the time steps given by me?

I simply don´t understand why this happens. I think I can work around the problem by integrating multiple times, but maybe someone knows a better solution. I apologize in advance in the case there already is a solution elsewhere and I haven´t seen it.

Comment: Great job in clarity and specificity for your first question. I can't help on this question; I was just reviewing it for quality, but you may want to post some code. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Odeint chooses its steps automatically, based on controlling the error estimate in the solution. "Excess work" means getting small error required too many steps, so the solution may not satisfy the accuracy you required. The time points you specify are only used for deciding at what points to report the results. The step control, required accuracy, and what is "excess work" is determined by the hmax, hmin, mxstep etc. options of the function.