# odeint floating point arithmetic

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, scipy, odeint

I am interessted in understanding the floating point arithmetics using the `scipy.integrate.odeint` function.

The case I am working with is the following

```
# data
omega = 136 # rad/s
d = 75 # Nm/s
k = 390000 # N/m
m = 4 # kg
n = 1000 # 
t_0 = 1 # s
t_1 = 5.5 # s
Y = 0.05 # m

# time
t = np.linspace(t_0, t_1, n)

# initial condition
x_0 = np.array([0, 0])

# first function
def fun(x, t, k, d, m, Y, omega):
    y = Y*np.sin(omega*t)
    return np.array([x[1], (y - k*x[0] - d*x[1]) / m])

# second function
def fun2(x, t, k, d, m, Y, omega):
    y = Y*np.sin(omega*t)
    return np.array([x[1], (-k*x[0] - d*x[1] + y)/m])

# results
res = odeint(fun, x_0, t, args=(m, k, d, Y, omega))
res2 = odeint(fun2, x_0, t, args=(m, k, d, Y, omega))
```

Note, that both functions are the same mathematically. The only difference is the order of numerical operations.

I would like to better understand the difference in the result `res - res2`, which is:

```
array([[  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
       [ -1.95628215e-22,   1.91508855e-19],
       [  6.33676391e-19,  -2.16307730e-17],
       ..., 
       [ -8.50849113e-10,   3.04613004e-09],
       [ -8.49843242e-10,  -9.43460353e-10],
       [ -1.00314946e-09,   4.45237878e-09]])
```

but it should be an array of zeros.

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing is the result of a different order for the floating point operations (addition and multiplication). See a classic paper http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html or wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Floating-point_arithmetic_operations

Even though the difference can be minor, as odeint solves to a given accuracy you are left with a difference that can be up to that treshold.

I don't know much about duplicates across SE sites but this is a close problem: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/10506/number-of-equations-and-precision-of-scipys-integrate-odeint
or this one [scipy.integrate.odeint fails depending on time steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40515064/scipy-integrate-odeint-fails-depending-on-time-steps) with a reply by a SciPy core developer.